# SQL - Update table column values using expression based on two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

Using a Sqlite database, I have a users table and a ranks table with the following columns:

users table:
id  |  rankid  |  xp

ranks table
id  |   name   | xpLowerLevel

My goal is update the rankId field for all user rows based on the xpLowerLevel field from the ranks table. My Sql expression as follows:

```
UPDATE users 
SET rankId = (SELECT id FROM ranks 
              WHERE xpLowerLevel <= users.xp  
              ORDER BY ABS(xpLowerLevel - users.xp) 
              LIMIT 1);
```

Which gives me the following error *no such column: users.xp*. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
UPDATE users 
SET rankId = (
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (ORDER BY ABS(xpLowerLevel - users.xp))
  FROM ranks 
  WHERE xpLowerLevel <= users.xp  
);
```

Or since there is already the condition:

```
WHERE xpLowerLevel <= users.xp
```

the difference:

```
users.xp - xpLowerLevel
```

is `>= 0`, 
so there is no need for the function `ABS()`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET rankId = (
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (ORDER BY users.xp - xpLowerLevel)
  FROM ranks 
  WHERE xpLowerLevel <= users.xp  
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly ! Thank you. If you have time on your hand I would really love to understand why this works and not my statement.

Comment: It must be a *feature* of SQLite which does not allow the use of a column from the outer query in the ORDER BY clause inside the correlated subquery. I tried the same code in Postgresql and it is syntactically correct: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WFq76NAjy5FgLY5AEj4Z7/1

Comment: Thank you for your time ! This should be the answer since it addresses my need to execute complex expressions in subqueries using outer table.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `order by` clause, where apparently SQLite does not accept references to the table being updated. But I am unsure that you need that reference anyway. Your column is named `xpLowerLevel`, which makes me think that you actually want:

```
update users
set rankid = (
    select id 
    from ranks
    where xpLowerLevel <= users.xp  
    order by xpLowerLevel desc
    limit 1
);
```

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to get the closest rank.xpLowerLevel below the user's current xp so the absolute difference of the 2 fields is a must.